# Laravel 5.2 cannot get name of current route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have followed instructions from [Taylor here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#accessing-the-current-route) but I cannot get this code working. I am trying to capture the `name` of the current route.

I have a class where I try and access the route. I have added a `use` statement at the top for the `Route` class:

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Route;
```

Inside the class I have the following method:

```
public function getTitle()
{
    $route = Route::current();
    $slug = $route->getName();

    return UserMenu::where('slug', '=', $slug)
        ->select()
        ->first()
        ->page_title;
}
```

But when my code hits the `$route =` line above it fails with:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::current()
```

Of course the method is not in the Route.php file. What have I missed?

Answer (score 1):

Ops! I needed to add:

```
use Route;
```